# Implement list using an array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am doing an assignment in which we have to create list of temperatures(double) and days(String), and implement the list using an array of objects. Each object stores the temp and the day and we can assign the temp and the day in our program. then sort with insertion alogrithm and output the original list and sorted list.

I placed the assignments of the temperature and the day under the dailyTemperature constructor and it compiles.  My last part is the for loop and if loop, I have it stating if getTemp is greater than 0 add to the getTemperature ArrayList, but I think this is wrong because getTemp does not have temperatures assigned to it. Would I have to assign the days and the temperatures separately in the dailyTemperature? Then call the variable which I assign the temperatures to in the if statement?

Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

public class dailyTemperature 
{

    //variables
    private double temperature;
    private String day;
    private static ArrayList<dailyTemperature> temp = new ArrayList<dailyTemperature>();


    //getTemp & setTemp methods
    public double getTemp()
    {
      return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemp(double newTemp)
    {
      temperature = newTemp;
    }

    //getDay & setTEmp methods
    public String getDay()
    {
      return day;
    }

    public void setDay(String newDay)
    {
      day = newDay;
    }


    public dailyTemperature(String dayInput, double temperatureInput) {
       this.day = day;
       this.temperature = temperature;
       temp.add(this);


      this.day = dayInput;
      this.temperature = temperatureInput;



    dailyTemperature[] getTemperature = new dailyTemperature[5];
    getTemperature[0] = new dailyTemperature("Mon", 70.0);
    getTemperature[1] = new dailyTemperature("Tue", 80.0);
    getTemperature[2] = new dailyTemperature("Wed", 65.2);
    getTemperature[3] = new dailyTemperature("Thur", 67.0);
    getTemperature[4] = new dailyTemperature("Fri", 68.5);


    }

    public static ArrayList<dailyTemperature> getTemperature()
    {
        ArrayList<dailyTemperature> getTemperature = new ArrayList<dailyTemperature>();
        for(dailyTemperature i : temp)
        {
            if(i.getTemp() > 0)
                getTemperature.add(i);
        }
        return getTemperature;
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: functions in java start with a lowercase letter; however the constructor matches the name of the class and therefore (by convention) starts with an Uppercase letter. As does the name of a class, so it's `DailyTemperature` not `daily....`

Comment: @Johan Thank you, I just changed them.

Comment: Your question is not clear -- "Would I have to assign the days and the temperatures separately in the dailyTemperature?" -- not sure what you mean by separately.  You already assign each value twice in the constructor, as well as creating and filling an array in the constructor.  I *think* the first three lines of your constructor are all that are needed, just end it after that.  Fill in the array in some other method.  And yes, temperatures can be negative, so I'd take that out.  If there's something that isn't working right in your code, you haven't mentioned it...

Comment: @rcook by first three lines you mean:

      this.day = dayInput;
      this.temperature = temperatureInput;
    
    DailyTemperature[] getTemperature = new DailyTemperature[5];

I am confused about how I am adding temperatures and days using just the get and set methods? Or is this line getTemperature[0] = new dailyTemperature("Mon", 70.0); adding the days and temperatures?

Comment: @rcook, you mean: the first **two** lines are all that is needed in the constructor. There should be no list in the `DailyTemp` class.

Comment: @SophiaAli - this needs a bunch of short questions and answers, inappropriate for comments.  If you care to go to the Java chatroom, we can try to handle it there.

Comment: @rcook yes that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Because this is homework, I'm not going to give you the complete ready made solution, but give you some pointers to help you on your way...

You're initializing a list of `DailyTemperature`'s in the constructor.
However that does not make sense because that list of local to the constructor and not accessable outside it.
Also in the class you are mixing things, in a way that does not make sense.

**Problems with the class**

```
public class DailyTemperature { 
    //variables
    private double temperature;   <<-- single element
    private String day;           <<-- single element
    private static ArrayList<dailyTemperature> temp = new ArrayList<dailyTemperature>
    ^
    +----- list of elements
```

This mix does not make sense.
You need to use separate classes for a single element and a list of the elements.

Something like:

```
public class DailyTemp {
  private double temperature;
  private Date day;
  //followed with getters and setters 
  //and a constructor
}

ArrayList<DailyTemp> dailyTemps = new ArrayList<DailyTemp>();
```

**Problems with the constructor**
You are assigning items to a local variable that goes out of scope as soon as you exit the constructor...

Let me show you:

```
  public DailyTemperature(String dayInput, double temperatureInput) {
   this.day = day;                   
   this.temperature = temperature;   <<-- so far so good.
   temp.add(this);        <<--- No, this is a single element, no lists in here

  this.day = dayInput;     <<-- user input should never be in a constructor
  this.temperature = temperatureInput;  <<--??

  dailyTemperature[] getTemperature = new dailyTemperature[5];  <<--see 
  getTemperature[0] = new dailyTemperature("Mon", 70.0);    <<---  comments
  getTemperature[1] = new dailyTemperature("Tue", 80.0);    <<---  below
  getTemperature[2] = new dailyTemperature("Wed", 65.2);
  getTemperature[3] = new dailyTemperature("Thur", 67.0);
  getTemperature[4] = new dailyTemperature("Fri", 68.5);
}
```

You declare a local variable `getTemperature`. This has the following problems:

1. `getTemperature` is a confusing name. `get`Something is what you name a getter. It is not a good name for a variable.
2. There is no way to access this local variable outside of the constructor, so you're doing all this work for nothing.
3. As soon as the constructor exits, `getTemperature` will go out of scope and will be destroyed by the garbage collector. So **even** if there was a way to access it, it would be destroyed before you could.

**Comments on coding style**
Names of classes start with a Capital letter.
functions and variable names start with an lowercase letter. Except for the constructor, this has the same name as the class and thus starts with an Uppercase letter.

I like the [K&R style of coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_true_brace_style#K.26R_style) where the opening `{` is on the same line. It keeps more code on screen. *(but that's just me and you may ignore this if you wish)*

Comment: I was confused on if I needed the get and set methods as well as the  dailyTemperature[] getTemperature = new dailyTemperature[5]; 

I am confused on how exactly I assign the create a list with the days and temperatures and then implement them using an array of objects

Comment: Each dailytemp stands on its own and only stores 1 day. Then you put those in a list. One at a time.

Comment: So you need two classes. One for the simple elements and One to hold the collective.

Comment: I am trying to create the second class, however when I extend to the first class I get an error saying constructor DailyTemperature in class DailyTemperature cannot be applied to given types; java.lang.String,double; found:no arguments; reason actual and formal
 arguments lists differ in length

does the new class need to extend the original class?

Comment: No, the first class is a single temperature element, the second is just you pushing elements around in a list. no extension. If you manipulate integers, do you extend the `integer` class?

Comment: I was supposed to implement a list using array of objects, is this right?

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DailyTemperatureList 
{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
   
    ArrayList<DailyTemperature> dailytemps = new ArrayList<DailyTemperature>();
    
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Mon", 78.1));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Tue", 79.3));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Wed", 81.2));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Thu", 83.0));
    dailytemps.add(new DailyTemperature("Fri", 85.3));
}

}

Comment: Now you're getting somewhere.

Comment: thank you for your help. Just one last question(sorry to keep bothering you) if I want to use an insertion sort to sort the temperatures do I have to save them in another array or can I keep them in the ArrayList and sort?

Comment: No, just make have the `DailyTemperature` class to implement the Comparable interface and then you can have the list to sort the items, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html It's real easy this interface has just one method.